# DateTime format for string

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string value that I need to change to DateTime and understand is valid or not.

the strings are like this one: for example **26.04.2021, Lunes**

I'm trying to getValue like below but It's not working.

```
var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact("26.04.2021, Lunes", "dd.MM.yyyy dddd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var validDate);
```

What the correct format for that?

Comment: "Lunes" isn't a valid day name in the invariant culture, and you've got an extra `,` in your input data that isn't in your format string.

Comment: @Llama Thanks for your comment, I tried to add extra **,** now but It's not working again. this is Spanish DateTime format. "Lunes" means Monday in Spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to pass the specific culture and also I think a comma (`,`) is missing from your format string:

```cs
var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact("26.04.2021, Lunes", "dd.MM.yyyy, dddd", new CultureInfo("es-ES"), DateTimeStyles.None, out var validDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

"Lunes" isn't a valid day name in the invariant culture. I'm assuming from that that the target language is Spanish, so I can declare the culture as such:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("es-ES");
```

The next issue you have is that your date has a comma in it, but your format doesn't, so we'll correct that:

```
"dd.MM.yyyy, dddd"
```

Putting this together we get:

```
var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact("26.04.2021, Lunes", "dd.MM.yyyy, dddd", culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var validDate);
```

Note that I've substituted `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with our `culture` variable.

The code now works.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/UDUQ95901)